# Connect divs with (non-straight) lines

Tags: php, css

I'd like to develop my site with a layout that looks somewhat like houses with connected plumbing, or multiple computers connected to a network. Basically, the will be boxes floating in space, with lines connecting some of the boxes. I'd like these lines to have some turns in them as well (just simple 90 degree corners) rather than just a straight line.

My question is what is the best way to achieve this, and perhaps a small example. My thoughts were to use:

**PHP and CSS:** I could create a background grid and then, with some complicated algorithms, draw paths using the grid's borders. This would be more dynamic, but I'm not sure I can plot the math all by myself.

**just CSS:** Perhaps this is as simple as making some pre-drawn lines like L-shapes and T-junctions, then just placing and scaling them. But I don't believe there's a way to scale an image by slicing it.. so the line width would be scaled and thus each image would look different.

Any thoughts?

Comment: [SVG](http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html) comes to mind.

Comment: Hmmm.. that page doesn't want to render on my cell. I'll have to wait til I get home to check that out.

Comment: Wow.. `Raphael` looks amazing! But it doesn't look like I would be able to apply something like `Paper.rect()` to a div full of content.

Comment: Although, I _could_ hide some `Raphael` elements behind my content then somehow tie the jQuery `draggable` events with the `Raphael` move events..

Comment: I ended up using Raphael. If you could post this as an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You, may be able to use some of jQuery's position & dimension functions and properties.

I.e. to get the off-sets and distances between div, which could then be used to 'draw' some extra div's as connectors.

Might be messy but would work.

Comment: Oh I see, I could use some 1px wide divs as the lines themselves.. good idea. But to make dynamic paths between divs it would still take some complicated math..